# Struggle with last output

Tags: c#

Car-Pool Savings Calculator (Project Name: CarPool) - Research several car-pooling websites. Include the links in your documentation. Create an app that calculates your daily driving cost, so that you can estimate how much money could be saved by car pooling, which also has other advantages such as reducing carbon emissions and reducing traffic congestion. The app should input the following information and display the user’s cost per day of driving to work:

Total miles driven per day.
Cost per gallon of gasoline (in cents).
Average miles per gallon.
Parking fees per day (in cents).
Tolls per day (in cents).

Here's my code that i did so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CarPool
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Variables used for input
            double dailyDistance;
            double pricePerGallon;
            double averageDistancePerGallon;
            double dailyParkingPayment;
            double tollPerDay;

            // Variables used for finding amount of gas
            double sumGallons;
            double pricePerDay;
            double fuelCost;

            // Input miles per day
            Console.Write("Total miles per day:");
            dailyDistance = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            // Input cost per gallon
            Console.Write("Cost per gallon of gasoline (in cents):");
            pricePerGallon = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            // Input miles per gallon
            Console.Write("Average miles per gallon:");
            averageDistancePerGallon = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            // input parking fees
            Console.Write("Parking fees per day (in cents):");
            dailyParkingPayment = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            // input toll fees
            Console.Write("Tolls per day (in cents):");
            tollPerDay = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            // finding pricePerDay
            pricePerDay = dailyParkingPayment + tollPerDay + fuelCost;

            // finding sumGallons
            sumGallons = dailyDistance / averageDistancePerGallon;

            // finding fuelCost
            fuelCost = sumGallons * pricePerGallon;

            // finding pricePerDay in dollars
            pricePerDay /= 100;

            Console.WriteLine("Total cost per day:" + $"{pricePerday:C2}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)"

Comment: When you compile this you will see a warning on the "finding pricePerDay" line. Read it and you will be able to work out what you have done wrong.

Comment: @iakobski i saw the error by the way thank you but it still doesnt print the number.

Comment: Also after debugging i have an error that's saying use of unassigned local variable 'fuelCost'. What does that mean?

Comment: pricePerDay = dailyParkingPayment + tollPerDay + fuelCost;
You use "fuelCost" but you do nothing on this variable before.

Comment: so how do i fix that @Olivier

Comment: Assign a value to it before using it

Comment: i don't how to assign 'fuelCost' a value to it

Comment: You do know - it's on the line after the comment `// finding fuelcost`. You need to remember that the instructions are run one after the other from top to bottom. So when it gets to the instruction `// finding price per day` it won't look ahead to find out what you want `fuelCost` to be, it will just use the value it is at that time - zero. Reorder the statements so that you calculate `fuelCost` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors. First, you have a assign a value to "fuelCost":

```
double fuelCost = 0;
```

Second, you wrote

```
Console.WriteLine("Total cost per day:" + $"{pricePerday:C2}");
```

but you forget a cap on day "pricePerday" ==> "pricePerDay"

Comment: Beside, you should use a IDE wich show you those kind of errors. And you may use decimal instead of double when you use prices. And use int instead of double if your numbers are not negatives.